# Bootstrap table: Is it possible to make a column/table use a stable sorting algorithm when sorting a column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make a bootstrap table use a stable sorting algorithm, so that it would be possible to reliably sort by more then one column without loosing all of the previous sort.

Answer (score 0):

[DataTable plugin for jQuery](http://datatables.net) could help you to [multiple sort](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html) a table and it's [bootstrap](http://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) compatible.